# Search Input for ANTD Table

Tags: reactjs, ajax, antd

I've managed to make a search input that allow search for the title and category of the project from the antd table but the initial data {dataSource} is not loaded with the data in dataLog (not sure is it because of AJAX request) and thus not loaded into the table, the data will only be shown when the first Search is performed at this case, here is my code:

[image]

```
const ListLogs = () => {
  const [logs, setLogs] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  // const [latestFive, setLatestFive] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const timeAgo = (prevDate) => {
    const diff = Number(new Date()) - prevDate;
    const minute = 60 * 1000;
    const hour = minute * 60;
    const day = hour * 24;
    const month = day * 30;
    const year = day * 365;
    switch (true) {
      case diff < minute:
        const seconds = Math.round(diff / 1000);
        return `${seconds} ${seconds > 1 ? "seconds" : "second"} ago`;
      case diff < hour:
        return Math.round(diff / minute) + " minutes ago";
      case diff < day:
        return Math.round(diff / hour) + " hours ago";
      case diff < month:
        return Math.round(diff / day) + " days ago";
      case diff < year:
        return Math.round(diff / month) + " months ago";
      case diff > year:
        return Math.round(diff / year) + " years ago";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  };

  const getAllLogs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/logs/");
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setLogs(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const expandedRowRender = () => {
    const columns = [
      { title: "Date", dataIndex: "date", key: "date" },
      { title: "Name", dataIndex: "name", key: "name" },
      {
        title: "Status",
        key: "state",
        render: () => (
          <span>
            <Badge status="success" />
            Finished
          </span>
        ),
      },
      { title: "Upgrade Status", dataIndex: "upgradeNum", key: "upgradeNum" },
      {
        title: "Type",
        dataIndex: "operation",
        key: "operation",
        render: () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Tag color="green">CREATE</Tag>
              <Tag color="gold">UPDATE</Tag>
              <Tag color="red">DELETE</Tag>
            </div>
          );
        },
      },
    ];
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      data.push({
        key: i,
        date: "2014-12-24 23:12:00",
        name: "This is production name",
        upgradeNum: "Upgraded: 56",
      });
    }
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  };

  const dataLog = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
    dataLog.push({
      key: i,
      category: <Tag color="default">{logs[i].category}</Tag>,
      title: logs[i].title,
      id: logs[i].id,
      lastUpdated:
        new Date(logs[i].last_updated).toLocaleString() +
        " " +
        timeAgo(new Date(logs[i].last_updated).getTime()),
    });
  }
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState(dataLog);
  console.log("dataSource: ", dataSource);
  console.log("dataLog: ", dataLog);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Category",
      dataIndex: "category",
      key: "category",
    },
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "title",
      key: "title",
    },
    { title: "ID", dataIndex: "id", key: "id" },
    { title: "Last Updated", dataIndex: "lastUpdated", key: "lastUpdated" },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setDataSource(dataLog);
    getAllLogs();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <header className="headerPage">
          <h1> Logs </h1>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <Input.Search
          placeholder="Input search text"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const currValue = e.target.value;
            setValue(currValue);
            const filteredData = dataLog.filter(
              (entry) =>
                entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(currValue.toLowerCase()) ||
                entry.category.props.children
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(currValue.toLowerCase())
            );
            console.log("filtered Data: ", filteredData);
            setDataSource(filteredData);
          }}
          // allowClear
          // onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          // style={{ width: 200, float: "right" }}
        />

        <Table
          bordered
          className="components-table-demo-nested"
          onRow={(i) => ({
            onClick: (e) => {
              history.push(
                `/admin/viewLog/${i.id}/${i.category.props.children}`
              );
            },
          })}
          columns={columns}
          // expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
          dataSource={dataSource} //tried {dataSource ? dataSource: dataLog} does not work as well
          size="small"
          pagination={false}
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default ListLogs;
```

Please enlighten me for this! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**:
When we call `setDataSource(dataLog)` inside the *useEffect* hooks for initial render (mounting) that would save empty array in `dataSource` variable, which can be used for showing empty list icon or loading, we have to set data source again when the data is fetched so, we can use another *useEffect* hook for `logs` state variable and set data source in it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDataSource(dataLog);
}, [logs]);
```

**Details**:

What we are trying to achieve with these hooks i.e. useEffect, is that we can write a code which can react when defined action occur, e.g. what we did in *useEffect* is that on initial render (mount phase), we set empty array and then call the API. After that when data arrives we set `logs` i.e. `setLogs(jsonData)`.

Which will populate the `logs` variable, then that loop come into play and `dataLog` will get filled but after that we never set the data source again with this `DataLog` i.e. filled list of objects (we only did that in for mount phase in which `dataLog` was empty, or when *onChange* get triggered)

So, a simple solution can be to use *useEffect* hooks for `logs` variable so, whenever the `logs` variable change, it will set the data source as well. As defined above in short answer.

Thus, with these hooks, we can significantly refactor this code.

**One More Thing**:
I recommend using `getAllLogs` function with `await` keyword, that will make that async code works like sync one i.e.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    await getAllLogs();
}, []);
```

I (try to) reproduce it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-antd-q17moy?file=List.js)